# How can I extract hashtags from string?

Tags: python, hashtag

I need to extract the "#" from a function that receives a string.
Here's what I've done:

```
def hashtag(str):
lst = []
for i in str.split():
    if i[0] == "#":
        lst.append(i[1:])
return lst
```

My code does work, but it splits words. So for the example string: `"Python is #great #Computer#Science"` it'll return the list: `['great', 'Computer#Science']` instead of `['great', 'Computer', 'Science']`.

Without using RegEx please.

Comment: are you trying to get the words starting with `#` symbol?

Comment: Have you tried using `split('#')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you split the string using default separator (space), you get the following result:

```
['Python', 'is', '#great', '#Computer#Science']
```

You can make a replace (adding a space before a hashtag) before splitting

```
def hashtag(str):
    lst = []
    str = str.replace('#', ' #')
    for i in str.split():
        if i[0] == "#":
            lst.append(i[1:])
    return lst
```

Answer (score 3):

Split into words, and then filter for the ones beginning with an octothorpe (hash).

```
[word for word in str.replace("#", " #").split()
    if word.startswith('#')
]
```

The steps are

- Insert a space in front of each hash, to make sure we separate on them
- Split the string at spaces
- Keep the words that start with a hash.

Result:

```
['#great', '#Computer', '#Science']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first try to find the firsr index where `#` occurs and split the slice on `#`

```py
text = 'Python is #great #Computer#Science'
text[text.find('#')+1:].split('#')
Out[214]: ['great ', 'Computer', 'Science']
```

You can even use `strip` at last to remove unnecessary white space.

```py
[tag.strip() for tag in text[text.find('#')+1:].split('#')]
Out[215]: ['great', 'Computer', 'Science']
```

Answer (score 1):

1. split by `#`
2. take all tokens except the first one
3. strip spaces

```py
s = "Python is #great #Computer#Science"
out = [w.split()[0] for w in s.split('#')[1:]]
out
['great', 'Computer', 'Science']
```

Comment: There are some cases where this will not work but they were not exposed in the question so I'm not sure it is a problem (e.g. `"Python is #great but needs some #time to be mastered #Computer#Science"`). Apart from that, definitely a straightforward way to solve the exposed problem.

Comment: you are correct. This can be easily generelized by `[w.split()[0] for w in s.split('#')[1:]]`